# How can I easily make my own jQuery accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I easily make my own jQuery accordion? I'd like to avoid wasting time trying to adapt other non-standard jQuery UI accordions.

Comment: @MikeBrant: You can answer your own questions. There's even a checkbox that allows you to post a question/answer combo at the same time. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I know I just wanted to share it here, even I've checked the Q&A style checkbox.

Comment: Looks like @Roko has an easier version

Comment: @sabithpocker: because he's smarter than me :(

Comment: Why not just use the normal, standard jQuery UI accordion rather than trying to adapt the "non-standard" accordions you allude to (but never mention by name/link)?

Comment: Why everyone keeps asking pointless things? I just wanted to share it. If you're not happy you can flag this question to be deleted. This is no contest, this is supposed to be a community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First: Get the jQuery library**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

**Second: Place this in your page**

```
<!-- NOTE: You MUST give a unique id to ALL the menu items -->
<div id="item1" class="menuItem">
    First Item
</div>
<div>text</div>
<div id="item2" class="menuItem">
    Second Item
</div>
<div>text</div>
```

**Third: Put the script wherever you want**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menuItem').next().css({ display: 'none' });

        $('.menuItem').click(function (event) {
            if ($('#' + event.target.id).next().css('display') == 'none') {
                collapseAll();
                $('#' + event.target.id).next().slideDown(500);
            }
        });
    });

    function collapseAll() {
        $('.menuItem').next().slideUp(500);
    }
</script>
```

**Bonus: You can place some images with avoiding headaches**

```
<div id="item1" class="menuItem">
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/icon.png")' alt="" />
    <span>First Item</span>
</div>
<div>text</div>
<div id="item2" class="menuItem">
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/icon.png")' alt="" />
    <span>Second Item</span>
</div>
<div>text</div>
```

**For the correct display of the images to the left of the text you will need some css format**

```
.menuItem img { float: left; }
.menuItem span { float: left; }
/* Avoided further styling for simplicity */
```

Comment: What wasn't working with the jQuery UI version? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2 class="h2toggle">title</h2>
    <div class="cont">content here</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.h2toggle').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this).next('.cont');  
    var vis = $el.is(":visible");
    $('.cont').slideUp();
    $el[ vis ? "slideUp" : "slideDown"]();
}).next('.cont').hide();
```

***[jsBin demo with + / - icons](http://jsbin.com/wirana/2/edit)***

Comment: roko please let me know if you have any idea how to add + - image icon in title right side and it change according to open and close. thanks.

Comment: also how to open one by default.

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas edited my answer and added a link

Comment: Thanks for this. but this is not my requirements, this is finding text + - and replacing and hiding, my requirement is I have 2 images 1st one contain plus sign in it and second minus and both are showing in right side of accordion. i want to display images on open and close not text. so please do me a favor and send me demo with images not text. Thanks.

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas you can extract the logic from the example above. Instead of changing text change classname to the `<i>` elements, In CSS you prepare the `.h2toggle i{}` and `.h2toggle i.close{}` and you simply toggle the `close` class using the `vi` variable. If you don't know how to do it ask a new question but show your attempt.

Comment: Thanks its done i used instead of image and make it like image using css. thanks.